# Linking error with cocoapods on simulator and device: Dsymutil

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, lipo, dsymutil

I have a project that recently, inexplicably stopped being able to run on both the simulator and the device. Everything compiles normally but there are two linker errors that occur.

The first is a lipo error:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Thirstie-fyibdehnqftrktbobkflxrtzenqr/Build/Intermediates/Thirstie.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Thirstie.build/Objects-normal/i386/Thirstie (No such file or directory)`

The second is a dsymutil error (cannot parse debug map):

```
GenerateDSYMFile ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Thirstie-fyibdehnqftrktbobkflxrtzenqr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Thirstie.app.dSYM ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Thirstie-fyibdehnqftrktbobkflxrtzenqr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Thirstie.app/Thirstie
    cd ~/Desktop/Thirstie/Thirstie
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Thirstie-fyibdehnqftrktbobkflxrtzenqr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Thirstie.app/Thirstie -o ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Thirstie-fyibdehnqftrktbobkflxrtzenqr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Thirstie.app.dSYM`

error: cannot parse the debug map for "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Thirstie-fyibdehnqftrktbobkflxrtzenqr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Thirstie.app/Thirstie": No such file or directory
```

I'm running Xcode 8.3.3 and iOS 10.

Some remedies I've tried:

1. `pod deintegrate && pod update && pod install`
2. Deleting derived data and cleaning the xcode project
3. Making sure `Build Only Active Architecture` is set to NO in both my pods target and my app target
4. Making sure `Enable Bitcode` is set to NO in both my pods target and my app target
5. Deleting the .xcworkspace entirely, cleaning the project, deleting derived data, and reinstalling the podfile

None of these has helped at all. Has anyone run into this before? I've gone through all of the different StackOverflow questions that seem related, but none of the remedies have helped. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Let me know if it would be useful for me to provide more information. Thank you!